# Does CockroachDB support read only mode?

Tags: sql, database, cockroachdb

Can you connect to CRDB in a read only mode? So that a connection cannot make any writes?

Answer (score 1):

There is no option on the server side to limit a connection to being read only. But at the transaction/session level you can set the transaction to be read only using the session variable `default_transaction_read_only` for example:

```
alyshan@serverless-us-c-1.gcp-us-central1.crdb.io:26257/defaultdb> set default_transaction_read_only = on;
SET


Time: 28ms total (execution 1ms / network 27ms)

alyshan@serverless-us-c-1.gcp-us-central1.crdb.io:26257/defaultdb> show default_transaction_read_only;
  default_transaction_read_only
---------------------------------
  on
(1 row)


Time: 29ms total (execution 1ms / network 28ms)

alyshan@serverless-us-c-1.gcp-us-central1.crdb.io:26257/defaultdb> insert into bar values (2);
ERROR: cannot execute INSERT in a read-only transaction
SQLSTATE: 25006
```